# determining which values were selected in html SELECT control with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<select id="MySelector" multiple="multiple">
  <option value="2">Option A</option>
  <option value="7">Option B</option>
  <option value="9">Option C</option>
  <option value="12">Option D</option>
</select>

<div id="CheckSelected">click here to select</div>
```

I'm looking to loop through the options of the select and determine which ones have been selected.

I'm looking to do something like this:

```
ArrayOfSelected = [];

$('#CheckSelected').click(function {

 "if option is selected then add value to the array"

});
```

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Is this a new array you're creating or do you have an existing array you want to add values to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$('#MySelector').val()` gives you an array containing the values of the selected elements.

Answer (score 2):

something like this should work for you.  Find the `option:selected` and for each one push the value into the array.

```
$('#CheckSelected').click(function() {
    ArrayOfSelected.length = 0; //empty the array.
    $("#MySelector option:selected").each(function() {
        ArrayOfSelected.push($(this).val());
    });
});
```

**[Code example on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/U9cs3/)**

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
ArrayOfSelected = [];

$('#CheckSelected').click(function {

   $('#MySelector option:selected').each(function(){
      ArrayOfSelected.push($(this).val());
   })

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with live select option box clicks rather than having to select an option then click the "click here to select" div. Do the following:

```
  var ArrayOfSelected = [];
  $('select#MySelector').change(function(){
      ArrayOfSelected.length = 0;
      ArrayOfSelected.push($(this).val());
      $("#picks").empty().append("<h1>selected: " + ArrayOfSelected + "</h1>");
 });
```

The .change() function tells the callback function to execute when an option within the specified select input has been changed. So for every option box click, the callback will be executed...

Doing it this way will reduce the number of clicks the user has to do in order to add an option to the array.

**update**

I tested this in your jsfiddle link and it works the way you are wanting.

Answer (score -2):

You can do it without looping with jQuery:

```
$('#CheckSelected').click(function() {
    if($('#MySelector').val() == 'your_option') {
        //add to array code
    }
}
```

Comment: this code is kind of useless... where does this if statement go?

Comment: If this if statement is outside of a loop then what initiates the if to execute? You didn't post enough code to help him out...

Comment: My bad, you both are right. You don't drink and code. I'll try to remember that tomorrow :D